# GMUClusterRendererDelegate show marker iconview only when cluster is rendered and not before that swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

i am trying to create clusters in my google map. When i show  clusters on map i want to show only the cluster count and when the cluster is clicked or zoom then only i want to show my Custom marker view. 
Bu the marker view are already present before clustering and when i zoom in a cluster, the default pins are shown, which i dont want.

below is the code for clustering

```
                        for data in self.map_data {
                            //check if map data is on or off and show map data accordignly
                            let offerdata = data
                            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
                            let strAddress = "\(offerdata.agent_street ?? "")"+" "+"\(offerdata.agent_city ?? "")"+" "+"\(offerdata.agent_zipcode ?? "")"

                            //MARK: GEOCODER FOR GETTING LAT LONG BASE ON ADDRESS
                            geocoder.geocodeAddressString(strAddress) {
                                placemarks, error in
                                let placemark = placemarks?.first
                                let lat =  Double(placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0.00)
                                let lon = Double(placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0.00)
                                print("Lat: \(String(describing: lat)), Lon: \(String(describing: lon))")

                                let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lon, zoom: 5)
                                let marker = GMSMarker()
                                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
                                marker.title = "\(offerdata.agent_firstname ?? "")"+" \(offerdata.agent_lastname ?? " ")"
                                marker.iconView?.backgroundColor = .lightGray
                                marker.userData  = data

                                //amrut
                                // Clustering
                                let item = POIItem(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon), name: "marker.title" ?? "",data: data)
                                self.clusterManager.add(item)


                                //map info views
                                var image = UIImage()
                                var currency  = String()
                                if data.currency == "AUD"{
                                    currency = "$\(data.currency ?? "")"
                                }
                                else if data.currency == "EUR"{
                                    currency = "€\(data.currency ?? "")"
                                }
                                else{
                                    currency = "£\(data.currency ?? "")"
                                }

                                let amount = "\(data.offer_amount ?? "")".convertTo2Decimal+" "+currency

                                //create custom marker accordin to condtions
//                                    "\(agent.offer_amount ?? "")".convertTo2Decimal+" "+"\(agent.currency ?? "AUD")"
                                if data.auto_approval_on_off == "ON"{
                                    if (data.is_badge_display == "1") {
                                        image = UIImage(named: "blueMarker.png") ?? UIImage()//blue
                                    } else {
                                           image = UIImage(named: "orangeMarker.png") ?? UIImage()//oranfge
                                       }
                                }
                                 else if (data.is_badge_display == "1") {
                                    image = UIImage(named: "blueMarker.png") ?? UIImage()//blue
                                } else {
                                    image = UIImage(named: "blackMarker.png") ?? UIImage()//black
                                }

                                let customMarker = CustomMarkerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40), image:image , lblText:amount)
//                                    marker.iconView=customMarker

                                marker.map = self.MapView
                                self.MapView.camera = camera
                            }
                        }
```

and the same thing i do when in 'GMUClusterRendererDelegate willRenderMarker' delegate method and just uncomment the **marker.iconView=customMarker**

can anyone please help me what i need to be doing. It will be really helpful
[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxerQ.png)
[Image for reference2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2ozK.png)

Two things i want:
1-  show clustering for initial load without map icon views 
2- show only map icon view and not the pins after cluster rendered/zoom

Please someone help me

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem similar to this. The work around I came up with was to run the clearMarkers function and then re-add the entire array of markers back in using the addMarkers function

I'm still working on this so if I find a better answer I'll update

Comment: Sure. I'll be waiting for the solution. If i found any, i'll post the solution